# Removing multiple elements from a matrix in octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

Say I have a matrix A.

```
A = [ 2 2 2; 
      3 3 3; 
      4 4 4; 
      5 5 5; 
      6 6 6]
```

And

```
B = [0 1 0 1 0]
```

And I would like to remove all the rows from `A` where `B == 1`

So after the operation I would want `A` to be

```
[ 2 2 2; 4 4 4; 6 6 6;]
```

How do I go about doing this ?

Comment: This logical indexing method might be better than actually removing those rows if it works on octave - `A = A(B~=1,:)`.But if you HAVE to use empty array assignment - `A(B==1,:)=[]`

Comment: Why does A(B, :) = [] not work but A(B==1, :) = [] does :|

I checked size(B) and size(B==1) both are 1 5 :|

Comment: Because B isn't a logical array to allow logical indexing. Convert B to logical array and then perform `A(B, :) = []` if you want to make it work that way.

Answer (score 2):

Use logical indexing

```
A(B~=1,:);
```

See code at [ideone](http://ideone.com/uAyUKj).

Answer (score 0):

Well, a pretty simple way is

`for x = 1..length(B)
  if (B(x) == 1)
   A(x,:)=[]
  endif
 end`

Comment: Isn't there any alternative to using loops ? I checked A(B', :) = []

But doesn't work